# the use of GLOBAL to solve the require(../../..) issue

Tags: node.js

I really gets tired of the obligation of relative paths in require().
What do you think about this solution? I'm not sure about the security implications.

```
GLOBAL.$require = function(mod){
   return require(path.join(__dirname, mod));
};
```

It keeps `node_modules` as base path of the default `require()`, but I added a `$require()` with path starting from the project root.

I didn't tried but the solution of edit NODE_PATH 
https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2014/02/20/how-i-work-around-the-require-problem-in-nodejs/
doesn't force you to change the path of all npm dependencies?